# How can I create a type that only accepts list of properties from another type?

Tags: typescript, types

I'm trying to create a "FormField" generic type which will take another type and only accept tuple of properties' name / value from this type + some properties such as "checked".

Example:

```
const formProperties: FormField<User> = [{name: "name", value: "Toto", checked: false}, {name: "age", value: 30, checked: true}]` with User defined like this : `interface User { name: string; age: number;}` or even `const formProperties: FormField<House> = [{name: "width", value: 100, checked: true}, {name: "height", value: 50, checked: false}]` with House : `interface House { width: number; height: number; }
```

I know that I could just use

```
{name: string; value: string | number | CustomType }[]
```

but then I could not know the type of "value".

I've also tried some things with mapped types but I didn't succeed either.

```
type FormField<T> = {[Property in keyof T]: T[Property]};
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I misunderstood your question, but shouldn't it be enough to simply type it as `FormField<T> = (T & { checked: boolean })[]`? If I see that correctly you want your "ListItem" to have all properties if your generic object plus the `checked` property.

Comment: @DivisionByZero That would result in something like this: `const fields: FormField<User> = [{name: "Toto", age: 30,  checked: false}, {name: "Tata", age: 31,  checked: true}]`, I don't want an array of T but an array T's properties/value : `const fields: FormField<User> = [{ name: "name", value: "Toto", checked: false}, {name: "age", value: 30, checked: true}]`
I would like to have a "checked" property for each property/value in T.

Comment: I noew understood your problem. [Have a look at my answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74824960/14392422)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

```
type FormFieldItem<T, Key extends keyof T> = {
  name: Key;
  value: T[Key];
  checked: boolean;
}

type FormField<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: FormFieldItem<T, K>;
}[keyof T][];
```

### What happens here?

For simplicity I extracted a single list item into it's own type `FormFieldItem`. This also makes it easier if you want to extend it in the future.
`FormFieldItem` takes two generic parameters:

- `T`: the entire object for mapping of the type of the specified `Key`
- `Key`: to map the type of the `key` property and the type of the `value` property

We can use the `FormFieldItem` type in our `FormField` type to first construct a new object where we map each key of the object (`T`) to the according `FormFieldItem`. Then we can map over the created object with all `keyof T`'s  to get a Union of all possible `FormFieldItem`'s.
Finally we expect a list of these unions (the last `[]`).

### Does it work?

You can test this with the values you gave in your description.
[Interactive TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9gJwLYwJYQDYBMCSwJIA8AKgDRQDSEIUEAHvgHZYDOUA1tXAGZTEB8UALxQA3gCgoURgEMkEAFyVqAbklQAbjIwBXRXwDaVEAF01UgMYALCBc5YlAIzhwMEGYzUBfceNCRYRBR0bBJBEQkpIyhURg4uXmITJXhkNExcfCIySn5vA04QHj4TAzNfWPwEbhkLaABVFggEMWk5fRZgBFiAcxUoGR79Rh0kR2b+n3ELOEZOqG4ggAUEOEgEYHQWFKD00Mbm8KgDdQB6U81tVCx1UTb5JQAiWXlH8i1dfUfiOGA4N6g1ls9iUNQwTSgXlIZwuH2ut3uX0GEABHz0SgAzAAGchAuwQBxQLp6SHQqTnGKMOE3KR3F5femo7ToqDY3E2fGE4nQKHiMxAA)

```
interface User { name: string; age: number; }

const formProperties: FormField<User> = [
  // valid
  { name: "name", value: "Toto", checked: false },
  // valid
  { name: "age", value: 30, checked: true },
  // invalid
  { name: "name", value: 30, checked: true },
];
```